# find commands with man pages

Tags: command-line, manpage

we use `man foo` to search about command `foo`. To know what is it and what its task and to find all switches.

But the point is when you want to **Do foo** and you do not know what is the command for that. I wish to find among man pages to know which command related to this?

**My question :**

is there any way to guess what is **appropriate command for your need** without access to internet and googling?  and finding them just by man on the terminal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no fix method of finding a command. But `man -k` may help you somewhat.

According to `man man`

```
man -k printf
       Search the short descriptions and manual page names for the keyword
       printf  as  regular expression.  Print out any matches.  Equivalent
       to apropos -r printf.
```

For example, if I want to search for a version control system, I may try

```
man -k 'version control'|grep ' (1)'
```

which shows

```
bzr (1)              - Bazaar next-generation distributed version control
```

But it did not show `git`, because it's short description is

```
git (1)              - the stupid content tracker
```

which does not match regexp "version control".

Answer (score 4):

If you know 'sorta' what your command is related to, you can use the `apropos` command:

```
xenon-lornix:~> apropos change directory

alphasort (3)        - scan a directory for matching entries
apt-listchanges (1)  - Show new changelog entries from Debian package archives
avahi-set-host-name (1) - Change mDNS host name
basename (1)         - strip directory and suffix from filenames
basename (1posix)    - return non-directory portion of a pathname
besside-ng-crawler (1) - filter EAPOL frames from a directory of capture files.
bindtextdomain (3)   - set directory containing message catalogs
BN_swap (3ssl)       - exchange BIGNUMs
brk (2)              - change data segment size
can_change_color (3ncurses) - curses color manipulation routines
can_change_color_sp (3ncurses) - curses screen-pointer extension
cd (1posix)          - change the working directory
chacl (1)            - change the access control list of a file or directory
chage (1)            - change user password expiry information
chattr (1)           - change file attributes on a Linux file system
chcon (1)            - change file security context
chdir (2)            - change working directory
chdir (3posix)       - change working directory
... and 400+ more ...
```

You received this many returns since `apropos` defaults to **or** mode... so anything that matches `change` **OR** `directory` is returned.  Whew!  Too many! (Although I can see the one we want here though)

```
xenon-lornix:~> apropos --and change directory

cd (1posix)          - change the working directory
chacl (1)            - change the access control list of a file or directory
chdir (2)            - change working directory
chdir (3posix)       - change working directory
chroot (2)           - change root directory
fchdir (2)           - change working directory
fchdir (3posix)      - change working directory
futimesat (2)        - change timestamps of a file relative to a directory file descriptor
git-stash (1)        - Stash the changes in a dirty working directory away
Linux::Inotify2 (3pm) - scalable directory/file change notification
mcd (1)              - change MSDOS directory
revpath (1)          - generate a relative path that can be used to undo a change-directory
```

This time, we only got 12 results, much better!  And you can see the `cd (1posix)` command which may be useful.  `man cd` or `man 1posix cd` will show you the man page.  And if you use the `bash` shell (or `zsh` or whatever...), always check their man pages too.  `man bash` and searching for `change` will get you close to bash's built-in cd command's description. (keep searching! It's in there!)

`apropos` gets it's information from a database built each night (cronjob), it really only searches the **name** and **description** sections of the man pages.  If you REALLY want to search for a keyword, use `man -K` (uppercase K there):

```
xenon-lornix:~> man -K M_CHECK_ACTION

(should bring up the man page for mallopt(3))
```

Do remember that this is a **BRUTE-FORCE** physical touch and search of **EVERY** man page on your system.  It can take a while!   Much faster after everything's been read in and cached though.

Just want a list of man pages with the particular keyword?

```
xenon-lornix:~> man -K -w MALLOC_CHECK_

/usr/share/man/man3/malloc.3.gz
/usr/share/man/man3/malloc_get_state.3.gz
/usr/share/man/man3/mallopt.3.gz
/usr/share/man/man3/mcheck.3.gz
```

Found in a few pages there.  (Capital Kay, lowercase double-ewe)

Have a look at the [`man`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/man) man page too, some interesting variations.